# Django form the cleaned_data field is None

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Django form the cleaned_data field is None.

This field has not passed the validation.

I want to change the value of this field.

Is there another way to get the non-valid fields?

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(Form, self).clean()

    print(cleaned_data.get('info')) <---- It is None

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. Pleas show us your full form class, and how you are handling it in the view.

Comment: Are you sure 'info' field is being filled in form? because you get None when that form field is empty else you get validation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cleaned_data is None, it should be because your existing form fields have not been validated or there is no data in them.

You can try something like this:

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    # Your fields here

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():    
             return super(forms.Form, self).clean() # Returns cleaned_data
        else:
             raise ValidationError(...)
```

EDIT: Taking note of what @Alasdair said - the following approach is better:

You could consider changing the value of 'info' beforehand, i.e. in the view, like so, instead of overriding the form's clean() method:

```
# In the view
data = request.POST.dict()
data['info'] = # your modifications here
form = Form1(data)
if form.is_valid():
     ...
```

Comment: Calling `form.is_valid()` will trigger the `clean` method, so you shouldn’t call `self.is_valid()` inside the `clean` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def content_view(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        context = {}
        choice = form.cleaned_data['choice']

        if form.cleaned_data['upload'] == None:
            upload = 'файл не загружен'
        else:
            file = request.FILES['upload']
            upload = file.read()

        context['choice'] = choice
        context['upload'] = upload
        return render(request, 'bot/content_result.html', context)
 else:
    form = ContentForm()
 return render(request, 'bot/content_view.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: you can use form.cleaned_data[] == None